# How to add a notification bar inside Microsoft Teams in-meeting tab?

Tags: microsoft-teams, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I'm developing a Microsoft Teams in-meeting app.

I want to add the notification bar at the exact position shown in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/design/designing-apps-in-meetings?tabs=desktop#anatomy-in-meeting-tab) document?

I'm trying to place all the notifications outside the iframe (just like it's shown in the document). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We checked with internal team and error banners are meant to be displayed within the iframe only, we have raised a bug from our side and the information on the document will be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the [Alert Component](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/0.57.0/components/alert/definition?showCode=true&showRtl=false&showTransparent=false&showVariables=false#slots-icon) to design the error notification.

Comment: Hi, the alert component is added inside the iframe. I want to know how it can be added outside the iframe like it's shown in the anatomy document.